# Programming Assignments-Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Still learning and I cant seem to wrap my head on what seemed like an easy task.
The computeMethods method's is where im totaly stumped, however the reverse method i just keep getting back the same integer without it being reversed.

```
  /****************************
        * For Method Computemethods1 i must compute series
        * b(x)=1/3+2/5+3/7..... +x/2x+1
        * For method ComputeMethod2
        * 1/2+2/3+......... x/(x+1)
        *******************************/
      public static int computeMethod1(int x){
        if (x==0)
          return 0;
        if (x==1)
          return 1;
        return computeMethod1(x-1/3/(x-1))+computeMethod1(x-2/3/(x-2));
      }


      public static int computeMethod2(int x){
        if (x==0)
          return 0;
        return computeMethod2((x-1)/(x-1)+1)+computeMethod2((x-2)/(x-2)+1);
      }
      /********************
        * For method reverseMethod i must reverse a user given int
        **********************/
      public static int reverseMethod(int x){
        int reversedNum=0;
        if (x!=0)
          return x;
        reversedNum=reversedNum *10 +x%10;
        return reversedNum+reverseMethod(x/10);


      }
      /******************
        * For method sumDigits i must use recursion 
        * to sum up each individual number within the int
        ********************/

      public static long sumDigits(long n){
        if( n==0)
          return 0;
        if (n==1)
          return 1;
        else
          return n+sumDigits(n-1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: `x-1/3` maybe a problem with integer division? Try using `float` or `double` numbers, i.e. `x-1./3.` Also change the methods' parameters accordingly. Also, you `sumDigits` seems to be a bit off... in fact, it's more like "sum of all numbers from 1 to n".

Comment: What's your question? You should specify what exactly doesn't work as expected. Also, please, remove irrelevant code.

Answer (score 2):

For reverse method, you are using: `if (x!=0) return x;`

May be you need to use: `if (x==0) return x`. So the logic is, if the given argument is 0, then return 0, else return reversed number.

P.S.: As somebody mentioned in comentaries, please take care of types, so for the division you are better using `float` or `double`, and take care of operations precedence for correct result, so `(x+1)/2` will be different from `x+1/2`.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your methods, follow through your code for small x.

For example, `computeMethod1` should return:

- `1/3` for `x == 1`, whereas at the moment it simply returns `1` (Note, the return type will need to be something other than `int`.).
- `1/3 + 2/5` for `x == 2`.
- `1/3 + 2/5 + 3/7` for `x == 3`.

For each `x`, notice how we can use the previous result i.e. `computeMethod1(x - 1)`.

When you come across code that doesn't seem to do what you expect, make your code simpler and simpler until you can narrow down where the problem is, then hopefully it will be obvious what the problem is, or online documentation can tell you.